# Test an Oracle DB connection in Java, with no username/password

Tags: java, database, oracle, database-connection

I know this is very similar to questions already answered, but there is a slight variation.

I have a list of connections in my production connection setup. The process is to start with the first and keep trying till I get a connection. I would like to be able to run a task that used this same list as its input, but did just enough to show which of the connections will be used by the application. To avoid our security team getting all upset, this would have to be done without the username/password.

Is it possible?

Comment: Not that I know of, nor should it be.  I don't see why you need anything beyond what every connection pool provides.

Comment: @Rajesh, I was hoping for a pure java solution, as then it would fit in with a   pre-existing application that checks similar details using dns lookups

Comment: Also, "TNSPING attempts to contact the corresponding listener. It does not actually determine whether the database is running." (Quoting @Rajesh's link.) So it wouldn't be a solution anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below answer may be helpful to you. `getErrorCode()` method in `SQLException` returns 1017 value on authentication failure. So you can iterate through list of connections and invoke `validateConnection`.

- I'm using dummy username and password here (I don't see any other option)
- Replace host, port and SID values.

  ```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      String connString = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@host:port:SID";
      System.out.println(validateConnection(connString));
  }

  public static boolean validateConnection(String connString) {

      try {
          Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
          Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connString, "x", "y");
      } catch (SQLException sqle) {
          if (sqle.getErrorCode() == 1017)
              return true;
      } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }

      return false;
  }
  ```